# Shortcut for autocompleting properties in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I was watching a video about C# and the guy used a shortcut to implement a property.

```
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

He wouldn't write the whole line, but instead let the visual studio editor fill in the get and set. Does anyone know the shortcut for completing the last part of the line above? Or even better, like a pdf quick-reference overview?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can type 'prop' then press tab twice. It's probably the same in earlier versions.

Edit: You'll then have to change the type (defaults to int) and the name (defaults to MyProperty).

Edit2: I've just found this great tool that allows you to edit these code snippets to override their default behaviour, or create new ones: http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/

Comment: These shortcuts are referred to as 'Code Snippets'. You can find a list of default snippets for VS2008 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Also, `propg` (for "property get") creates a property with a public getter and a private setter.

Comment: @Aasmund: Very useful - I'll definitely start using that.

Comment: Try to install Resharper, you will get some other goodies as well

Comment: @anvarbek: In the process of trying to get work to cough up for ReSharper - it's awesome, but spending money goes against the grain here :(

Comment: Thank you all. I will be studying the code snippet article:-)

Comment: It's just a single tab in VS 2013.